# Is there a way to automate conversion from Word Phonetic Guides to HTML <ruby>?

Tags: html

I have a number of Japanese songs I translated into Italian and possibly other languages, and I put furigana (pronunciation in Hiragana) on every kanji via the phonetic guide function in Microsoft Word. All of these will sooner or later have to end up [on my blog](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/09/blog-index.html), which obviously means either losing the phonetic guide or painstakingly typing `<ruby>`, `<rt>` and `</rt></ruby>` a million times to convert the phonetic guide into `<ruby>` and have it appear in the posts. I am using a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks installed, in case it is of use. I was wondering: is there a way to make this conversion automatic?

Sorry, this may be [plz-send-teh-codez](/questions/tagged/plz-send-teh-codez), but I don't know where else to look, since Googling "converting word phonetic guide to HTML ruby" doesn't seem to get useful results… should I just ask on Quora? And get the question marked as needs editing with a 50% change? What is best, near-100% closing chance or 50% needs editing chance? Hmm…

I honestly have no idea what language I want to use, but Java would at least be somewhat familiar since I've taken two courses on it a few years ago.

Comment: TIL "ruby" is an HTML tag, You'll notice if you hover over the "ruby" tag you gave to this question that it is a programming language. So, unless you want to use the Ruby programming language for this (which you could do), it might be better to tag it as `html`

Comment: @maxpleaner Good catch. I honestly have no idea what language I want to use, but Java would at least be somewhat familiar since I've taken two courses on it a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

One way to partially automatize it is to copy-paste the thing into the HTML editor in Blogger (or any plain text editor), thus making the phonetic guide show up in brackets next to what it guides (e.g. the equivalent of `<ruby>text<rt>guide</rt></ruby>` shows up as "text(guide)", then replace all "("s with `<rt>` and all ")"s with `</rt></ruby>`, which leaves only `<ruby>` to type, so one puts that in the clipboard and looks for `<rt>` to find where it should be pasted. This is not totally automated, but it definitely speeds the procedure up, I think.